# How to navigate from Javascript to a MVC5 controller with a complex type as parameter in Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

In my webapp I have a need to navigate from JavaScript to a different page (MVC5 controller action) and passing in a complex type as a parameter. How can I do this?

The (Typescript) interface of the complex type:

```
interface IReferences {
    UserId: System.IGuid;
    ProjectId: System.IGuid;
    TaskToDoId: System.IGuid;        
    TenantId: System.IGuid;
}
```

The controller is quite simple:

```
public class TaskToDoDetailsController : Controller {
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult TaskToDoDetails(References references)      {
        return View(references);
    }
}
```

I've tried a Ajax call and use document.write(data) to update the page. This has some disadvantages, like losing all the nice debugging features in Visual Studio and it does not work correctly in all circumstances.

Also tried this:

```
$("#Imp").load(url, { references: payload })
```

But the payload (the complex type) is not received by the controller action. (UserId, ProjectId etc. are NULL).

Options that I've found in StackOverflow talk about a call to a WebApi, but the key difference is that I have to show the result in a webpage.

SOLUTION (thanks to @dknaack) :

```
$("#Imp").load("/Issue/IssueDetails, payload)
```

Comment: What does the controller method look like in C#?

Comment: @GregBurghardt I've updated the question with the controller information.

Comment: Unless something has changed with MVC5, I don't think the ModelBinder can translate the HTTP request parameters to an interface. I think you need a concrete type as an argument to your controller method.

Comment: @GregBurghardt Thanks, I've tried a concrete type in de controller, but that doesn't work either. The interface above is a Typescript Interface at the client side. (updated the question also with this info)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to use jQuery for that.

Check out [AJAX calls to ASP.NET MVC action methods using jQuery](http://blog.bobcravens.com/2009/11/ajax-calls-to-asp-net-mvc-action-methods-using-jquery/)

Comment: The used example (Load an MVC Partial View) in your link, does not cover a complex type and when I try to pass my complex type, the values are not received by my controller (UserId, ProjectId etc. are NULL). Fiddler sees the values under the 'WebForms' tab (references[UserId] etc), but it seems that the modelbinder can't copy with that

Comment: I've figured it out with the help of your information. The call should be: $("#Imp").load("/Issue/Issuedetails", payload);